# CASE statement not working after switching to Oracle Provider for OLE DB

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2008, ssis, case-statement

I am currently migrating SSIS packages from VS2008 to VS2012 to run on a 64-bit server and have come across an issue I can't seem to find a resolution to online. We have several Data Flow tasks that connect and pull data from different Oracle servers. We used the "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle" for most of our Data Flow tasks but it appears the Microsoft provider does not have a 64-bit version.

So, I created a new connection manager with the "Oracle Provider for OLE DB" with a successful connection test. I'm aware that there are differences between TSQL and PLSQL, also differences in how the Oracle provider reads in data compared to the Microsoft provider (inline comments, square brackets...etc), but I can't seem to pinpoint why the following code is failing when I try to preview the results. I believe the issue lies in the CASE statement because when I completely take the case statements out the preview runs fine.

Also, this code runs fine with the Microsoft Provider and also works in TOAD when directly connecting to the Oracle database.

```
/*----My example code---*/

SELECT  
    CASE  
        WHEN ORDER_NUM IS NOT NULL  
        THEN 1   
        ELSE 0  
    END AS ORDER_FLAG  
FROM TABLE1

/*----END My example code---*/
```

ERROR:

> "There was an error displaying the preview.    ORA-00905: missing
>   keyword(OraOLEDB)"

SPECS:
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 - Professional
Version 9.0.30729.4462 QFE
Version 3.5 SP1

SQL Server Integration Services
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 10.50.4000.0

SOLUTION:
Thank you all for your help. After researching the suggested items I've found a "solution". Solution: I installed Oracle 10g, restarted pc, works fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Nice first post - you've provided the code that reproduces the behavior, the error message, and the expected and actual outcomes.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the Oracle Provider for OLE DB?  There have been bugs with "SELECT CASE..." statements in some versions.  For example, version 9.2.0.4.0 fixed two such bugs (https://community.oracle.com/thread/216936).

Comment: I see there are many versions of the Oracle Provider. How do I know which version of Oracle Provider I'm using and how do I know I'm getting the right version?

I'm using Oracle 9i.

Comment: Personally I only install 32-bit drivers to avoid this sort of issue. Visual Studio is 32-bit, so therefore I force 32-bit execution of SSIS packages for a consistent runtime environment.

Comment: @peppep1101, look in your Oracle home directory for the oledb directory.  It usually has a readme file with the version in it.  On Windows the path is something like: C:\oracle\product\{oracle_version}\client_1\oledb.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. After researching the suggested items I've found a "solution".  

Solution: I installed Oracle 10g, restarted pc, works fine... smh

Comment: @peppep1101 Could you please post this as an answer and mark it as accepted? That way, future readers will know immediately how they can fix this problem.